# "Subscript out of range" error when I divide 1 Sub into 2 Sub's in VBA-Excel

Tags: sql, arrays, sql-server-2008, excel, vba

I wrote a VBA-SQL code in a "Module" which reads a table from a sheet, then it sends the table to server via SQL-code.  I am saving each column as an array `result1(), result2(), result3()`, and `Col1, Col2` are just column names in the server. `it` is index for the arrays (same index for all arrays) The VBA-SQL code is something like this. And this `Sub` works perfectly:

```
Sub Datasend_Click()

Dim result1() As Variant, result2() As Variant, result3() As Variant
Dim Col1 As String, Col2 As String, Col3 As String
Dim it As Integer

    Set ValidSheet = Worksheets("Sheet2")
    Set DataRange = ValidSheet.Range("C22:C81")
        it = 1
    For Each dataa In DataRange
        ReDim Preserve result1(it)
            result1(it) = dataa.Value
            it = it + 1
    Next


     Set DataRange = ValidSheet.Range("D22:D81")
        it = 1
    For Each dataa In DataRange
        ReDim Preserve result2(it)
            result2(it) = dataa.Value
            it = it + 1
    Next

 For it = 1 To 60

    SQL = "INSERT INTO PaymentPattern (" & Col1 & ", " & Col2 & ", " & Col3 & ") "
    SQL = SQL & "VALUES (" & Str(result1(it)) & ", " & Str(result2(it)) & ", " & Str(result3(it)) & ")"

    dbclass.ExecuteSQL SQL

  Next it

End Sub
```

However, I want to separate this `Sub` into 2 `Sub's` instead. The first `Sub`  will read and save the arrays from the sheet (then I can use the arrays for other `Sub's`), and the second `Sub` will call the first `Sub`and run the SQL-code to send the arrays to the server. I wrote 2 `Sub's` like below, but I get an error like "Subscript out of range" for the line `SQL = SQL & "VALUES (" & Str(result1(it)) & ", " & Str(result2(it)) & ", " & Str(result3(it)) & ")"`. When I debug it, it shows that `it=1` as normal, but it shows "Subcript out of range" for the `result1(it)`. Can you say please what is wrong?

```
Sub arrayread()
  Dim result1() As Variant, result2() As Variant, result3() As Variant
  Dim it As Integer

    Set ValidSheet = Worksheets("Sheet2")
    Set DataRange = ValidSheet.Range("C22:C81")
        it = 1
    For Each dataa In DataRange
        ReDim Preserve result1(it)
            result1(it) = dataa.Value
            it = it + 1
    Next


     Set DataRange = ValidSheet.Range("D22:D81")
        it = 1
    For Each dataa In DataRange
        ReDim Preserve result2(it)
            result2(it) = dataa.Value
            it = it + 1
    Next


End Sub
```

---

```
Sub Datasend_Click()
  Dim result1() As Variant, result2() As Variant, result3() As Variant
  Dim it As Integer
  Dim Col1 As String, Col2 As String, Col3 As String

  arrayread

  For it = 1 To 60

    SQL = "INSERT INTO PaymentPattern (" & Col1 & ", " & Col2 & ", " & Col3 & ") "
    SQL = SQL & "VALUES (" & Str(result1(it)) & ", " & Str(result2(it)) & ", " & Str(result3(it)) & ")"

    dbclass.ExecuteSQL SQL

  Next it

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It comes down to the scope of the arrays (where they are declared).  You are declaring them separately in each sub, so `result1` in Datasend_Click knows nothing about `result1` from `arrayread`.  Therefore, `result1` and `result2` will be empty in the second sub which causes your `Subscript out of range` error, given you have no elements yet you are trying to access it.

Here is a Microsoft article outlining VBA variable scope: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/141693.  Chip Pearson also has a good article on this subject: http://www.cpearson.com/excel/scope.aspx

You should move the declaration of `result1` and `result2` to the top of your `Module` (above the `Sub`s) so they they have Class Level scope (available to all methods in the Module).

```
Dim result1() As Variant, result2() As Variant, result3() As Variant


Sub arrayread()
  Dim it As Integer

    Set ValidSheet = Worksheets("Sheet2")
    Set DataRange = ValidSheet.Range("C22:C81")
        it = 1
    For Each dataa In DataRange
        ReDim Preserve result1(it)
            result1(it) = dataa.Value
            it = it + 1
    Next


     Set DataRange = ValidSheet.Range("D22:D81")
        it = 1
    For Each dataa In DataRange
        ReDim Preserve result2(it)
            result2(it) = dataa.Value
            it = it + 1
    Next


End Sub

Sub Datasend_Click()

  Dim it As Integer
  Dim Col1 As String, Col2 As String, Col3 As String

  arrayread

  For it = 1 To 60

    SQL = "INSERT INTO PaymentPattern (" & Col1 & ", " & Col2 & ", " & Col3 & ") "
    SQL = SQL & "VALUES (" & Str(result1(it)) & ", " & Str(result2(it)) & ", " & Str(result3(it)) & ")"

    dbclass.ExecuteSQL SQL

  Next it

End Sub
```

My preferred solution would be to be passing the results in and out of the methods rather than having module-level scope, as this can cause spaghetti code issues down the track.